# (Python)Formatting the elements in my list

Tags: python

So i'm trying to get the elements in my list to be 7 bytes long but I had no luck in trying to do that myself.

```html
redChannelData = [46, 49, 50, 51, 53, 53, 54, 56, 59, 59, 60, 61, 62, 62, 64, 64, 65, 65]
redChannelList = []
for value in redChannelData:
    redChannelListBinary = bin(value)[2:]
    redChannelList.append(redChannelListBinary)
redChannelListBinaryList = [[int(b) for b in binary] for binary in redChannelList]
print(redChannelListBinaryList)
```

Output:

```html
[[1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the format function and specify that I am interested up to 7 bits.

```
redChannelData = [46, 49, 50, 51, 53, 53, 54, 56, 59, 59, 60, 61, 62, 62, 64, 64, 65, 65]
redChannelList = []
for value in redChannelData:
    redChannelListBinary = format(value, '07b')
    redChannelList.append(redChannelListBinary)
redChannelListBinaryList = [[int(b) for b in binary] for binary in redChannelList]
print(redChannelListBinaryList)
```

gives output

```
[[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

Comment: oh lol, the one variable I D'DINT try to change was the answer. thanks ^^

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```html
redChannelData = [46, 49, 50, 51, 53, 53, 54, 56, 59, 59, 60, 61, 62, 62, 64, 64, 65, 65]
redChannelList = []
for value in redChannelData:
    redChannelListBinary = bin(value)[2:]
    while len(redChannelListBinary) < 7:
        redChannelListBinary = '0' + redChannelListBinary
    redChannelList.append(redChannelListBinary)
redChannelListBinaryList = [[int(b) for b in binary] for binary in redChannelList]
print(redChannelListBinaryList)
```

the output:

```
[[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
```